# Replacing value of key in settings.yml using rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a key in rails application /my_app/config/settings.yml

age: 25

I want to replace value of age from 25 to whatever user enters using ruby code.
How can i do it. Is it necessary to load the file first before writing the value?

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in write mode

Read and parse the yml content from your file.

Replace the value

Write yml values into original file or a new file.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Rails provides internationalization support for static content , `has_translations` complements that and provides internationalization support for dynamic contents.

The gem can be find from [here](https://github.com/nmindia/has_translations).

Comment: Hey ur post is saying modifying table or databse. But i want to replace value of a key in setting.yml. I have to deal with files not database